# How to use -a in command line?

Tags: karate

As documented for standalone-jar I'm trying to provide args to my feature and can't figure how to get it work. what do I miss ?

My command line :

```
java -jar c:\karate\karate-0.9.1.jar -a myKey1=myValue1 TestArgs.feature
```

karate-config.js

```
function fn() {   
  var env = karate.env; 
  karate.log('karate.env system property was:', env);
  if (!env) {
    env = 'test';
  }
  var config = { // base config JSON   
    arg:karate.properties['myKey1']    
  };
  return config;
}
```

TestArgs.feature
    Feature: test args

```
Scenario: print args

* print myKey1
* print arg
* print karate.properties['myKey1']
* print karate.get('myKey1')
```

I don't get anything printed :
java -jar c:\karate\karate-0.9.1.jar -a myKey1=myValue1 TestArgs.feature

10:32:57.904 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate.netty.Main - Karate version: 0.9.1

10:32:58.012 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate.Runner - Karate version: 0.9.1

10:32:58.470 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - karate.env system property was: null

10:32:58.489 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print]

10:32:58.491 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print]

10:32:58.495 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print]

10:32:58.501 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually we meant to delete the docs, apologies since the `-a / --args` option is not supported any more.

You can of course use the `karate.properties['some.key']` approach to unpack values from the command-line. Also refer how you can even get environment variables: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/547

My suggestion is you can use `karate-config-<env>.js` to read a bunch of variables from a file if needed. For example, given this feature:

```
Feature:

Scenario:

* print myKey
```

And this file `karate-config-dev.js`:

```
function() { return { myKey: 'hello' } }
```

You can run this command, which will auto load the config js file:

```
java -jar karate.jar -e dev test.feature
```

We will update the docs. Thanks for catching this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. the args I wanted to provide are independant from environment (ie dev vs int) and I already use "-e", so this won't work. Environment variable works fine. How can I some.key via command line in order to read it with karate.propertis['some.key'] ?

Comment: Can't edit my previous comment. Could you please provide a sample command line which may work with the karate.properties feature ? thks

Comment: @PaulAngevelle sure. try `java -jar -Dsome.key=hello karate.jar test.feature`

Comment: yeah, karate rocks ! For non java users (like me), -D will only work if it's before karate.jar in the command line.